# Ruby - Iterate over array of hashes and sum/compact the values of duplicate keys

Tags: ruby

`arr = [{"94838"=>30.0}, {"94916"=>2.0}, {"94916"=>10.0}]`

I'm trying to iterate over each of the hashes and sum the values of all matching keys. Furthermore, to merge each hash into one (since there will be no more chance of dupe keys)

The expected output would be:
`{"94838"=>30.0, "94916"=>12.0}`

I found a way to do this but it seems gross -

```
arr.inject do |id, qty|
  id.merge(qty) {|_k, old_v, new_v| old_v + new_v }
end
   .compact
   .sort
   .to_h
```

I guess my question to more experienced programmers is; does this look OK? I just can't help but feel like there's a better way to do this - thank you :)

Comment: You can remove the `.compact.sort.to_h` part. The remaining `inject` + `merge` doesn’t look gross at all to me: `inject` combines the array’s hashes using a binary operation which is `Hash#merge`.  And the block to `merge` ensures that duplicate keys calculate the sum of their values (instead of overwriting one another). Quite elegant actually.

Comment: I like your approach. While it may look sort of computer-y, this sort of chained expression is to-the-point and I would say idiomatic. Obviously, chaining expressions can get a little over-the-top sometimes but at the same time, it's nice to avoid intermediate variables that you don't really care about. And, they're more easy to make lazy, should you find a need for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with a straightforward iteration through all the items?

```
arr = [{"94838"=>30.0}, {"94916"=>2.0}, {"94916"=>10.0}]

hsh = Hash.new(0)  # Default value for each key is zero

# For each hash in arr, iterate through each key/value pair and
# increment the destination total associated with the key by the
# current value. Can use increment because of the zero default. 
arr.each { |h| h.each { |k, v| hsh[k] += v } }
p hsh    # Produces {"94838"=>30.0, "94916"=>12.0} as desired
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can get all keys with:

```
uniq_keys = arr.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq
```

We can then map that to the values of those in the hashes and use `#compact` to throw away the nils for hashes that don't have that key, use `#sum` to sum up the numbers, then turn that to a hash.

```
uniq_keys.map { |k| [k, arr.map { |h| h[k] }.compact.sum] }.to_h
```

And we end up with:

```
{"94838"=>30.0, "94916"=>12.0}
```

This can also be solved using `#each_with_object`.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |hsh, result| 
  hsh.each_pair { |k, v| 
    result[k] ||= 0
    result[k] += v 
  } 
}
# => {"94838"=>30.0, "94916"=>12.0}
```

Here we're iterating with a hash object called `result`. For each hash in the array, we iterate over its key/value pairs, setting them by default to `0` in `result` if they don't yet exist in `result`, before adding their current value.